# ARM Keil Factorial function

Tags: loops, assembly, arm, keil

I'm trying to calculate 10! with ARM Assembly Code, but I am stuck in infinite r0 r0 movs loop in line 45 (LDMFD sp!, {r4, pc}). It seems that I have made many mistakes.

Anyone please, would you like to help me to fix errors? If possible, I would prefer not to modify the entire structure of the code, including annotations. Thank you!

```
AREA Reset, CODE, READONLY
    ENTRY
SRAM_BASE EQU 0x40000000
    EXPORT Reset_Handler

Reset_Handler
    ; Set the stack memory location.
    LDR sp, =SRAM_BASE + 100
    ; Pass the function parameter n value as 10 using the MOV command to the register that holds the parameter.
    MOV r0, #10


    ; Insert the code that calls the function to calculate factorial. The function name is CalcFacto in this case.

BL CalcFacto 

; Verify the returned value using the register that received the value, and exit the program.

stop B stop
    

CalcFacto
        ; while callee-saved registers are used to store values that must be preserved and include r4-r11 and lr.
        ; Save r4 and lr registers that will be used for calculation on the stack using stack operation commands.

    STMFD sp!, {r4, lr}
    MOV r4, #1 ; n = 0 , n! = 1
    CMP r0, #0 ; compare if n value is 0

sub_loop   ; perform multiplication operation using loop until n value becomes 0

        ; store the multiplication result in r4
    MULGT r4, r4, r0 

        ; Compare if the value obtained by subtracting 1 from the n value is greater than 0.
    SUBGTS r0, r0, #1

        ; Branch to loop if the n value is greater than 0
    BGT sub_loop

        ; Return the result value as per AAPCS using r0 and r1 registers.
    MOV r0,r4

        ; At the end of the function, restore the value of the r4 register, and store the lr register value as PC to return.
    LDMFD sp!, {r4, pc}

    END
```

Comment: There is no line 56.  That text is 47 lines long

Comment: @ErikEidt sorry for that, it is line 45 -  LDMFD sp!, {r4, pc}

Comment: The code looks reasonable to me (not sure why you're using conditional multiplication and subtraction, but should still work). Are you able tp single step in a debugger?

Comment: @ErikEidt I had tried to do so using these buttons(https://www.keil.com/products/uvision/db_exe_step.asp) but always pc moved to 0x000AF04E and greater address and stuck in r0 r0 MOVS loop. Or if the code is reasonable, Did I use the wrong project settings? I was using Keil uvision4.74 and TM4C1233H6PM cpu, ULINK2/ME Cortex Debugger.

Comment: @ErikEidt Thank you sir, I changed the cpu to LPC2104, and tried single step in a debugger. It really worked and I got 375F00 on r0, which equals to 10!=3628800